# android mediaplayer wont play wav file from url

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i have a mediaplayer, and i want to read an audio file from a url, (wav format)
here is the code

```
public static void startMediaPlayer(String url) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        mediaPlayer.start();

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

then i get the error

```
10-25 17:01:45.015: E/MediaPlayer(2e745): Error (-38,0)
10-25 17:01:47.281: E/MediaPlayer(26745): error (1, -1004)
```

the file is readeable in VLC though

Comment: How long is the track? Have you tried SoundPool? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Comment: the track is 29 seconds long, and no i haven't tried that, in fact, never tried it beforeis there a way to make it work

Comment: Usually I would recommend SoundPool but the size should not exceed 1 MB

Comment: you are welcome. If you want to compress it without loosing quality you can use monkeys audio: http://www.monkeysaudio.com/ and then via for example Total audio converter convert it to mp3-format.

Comment: is there an example for how to load a url with SoundPool? i can't seem to find it

Comment: maybe through the following method: public int load (String path, int priority) but I am not sure. See the docs

Comment: what url you are passing? url=??